# Aligning multiple pieces of text in different places

Tags: html, css

I want my email and the word 'email' to align on the right. I understand my email will be longer on the left.

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="background: #000; height: 80px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <h1 style="font-family: Snell Roundhand, cursive; padding-left: 10px; color: white; float: left;">New Trend Photography</h1>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p style="font-size: 14px; color: white; float: right; padding-right: 10px;">E-mail</p>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div>
        <p style="font-size: 20px; color: white; float: right; padding-right: 10px;">newtrendphotography23@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="background: #000; height: 80px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <h1 style="font-family: Snell Roundhand, cursive; padding-left: 10px; color: white; float: left;">New Trend Photography</h1>
    <div>
      <div style="font-size: 14px; color: white; float: right; padding-right: 10px;text-align:right">
        <p>E-mail</p>
        <p>newtrendphotography23@gmail.com</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Add style to one div only

Comment: No. This aligned the two paragraphs to the left of each other, I want both paragraphs as far right as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nest elements into one parent element, and declare positioning and alignment rules as needed to the parent element.

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="background: #000; height: 80px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <h1 style="font-family: Snell Roundhand, cursive; padding-left: 10px; color: white; float: left;">New Trend Photography</h1>
    <div>
      <div>
        <p style="font-size: 14px; color: white; float: right; padding-right: 10px; max-width: 35%;">E-mail: <a href="mailto:newtrendphotography23@gmail.com">newtrendphotography23@gmail.com</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in two ways.
Firstly put both of them in one paragraph with `float:right`.

1. You can use `text-align: right;` to the `<p>` to get them right aligned.

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="background: #000; height: 200px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <h1 style="font-family: Snell Roundhand, cursive; padding-left: 10px; color: white; float: left;">New Trend Photography</h1>

    <p style="font-size: 14px; color: white; float: right; padding-right: 10px; max-width: 35%; text-align: right;">
      E-mail: 
      <br> newtrendphotography23@gmail.com
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Inside the `<p>` use a `<span>` with `float: right` on the "E-mail:", so that it floats to the right inside the paragraph that is floating to the right.

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="background: #000; height: 200px; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <h1 style="font-family: Snell Roundhand, cursive; padding-left: 10px; color: white; float: left;">New Trend Photography</h1>

    <p style="font-size: 14px; color: white; float: right; padding-right: 10px; max-width: 35%;">
      <span style="float:right">E-mail: </span>
      <br> newtrendphotography23@gmail.com
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

No.1 is the better solution as the text is by default left-aligned and that is what is causing the issue, not that the text is not floating to the right.